# How to inform a visually impaired user when an action is processing

Tags: website-design, mobile-application

I'm currently working on a task whereby the backend will load plenty of options(Trip planner). When an action is processing with voiceover on, this may take 10+ seconds to load all options.

**What are some ways (or best practices, if any) to inform a visually impaired user about delay/wait time due to processing?**

Comment: You cannot rely on the visual feedback, so add some sound. When making phone call, you hear beeps as the sonic feedback. You can play with Siri or Google Assistant to explore the sonic feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One definite way is to add sound feedback that tells or depicts to the user its loading. That way, the user is certain something is going on and over time gets used to it whenever it is triggered.